# How to add a new page and add all products to it in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce

this might be very easy question. I am trying to add a page and then have that page added to navigation bar and then i want that page to have all of my products and categories on the side. i dont have a lot of products so i thought it would help to have them all on one page. like a products page.

thank you

Comment: google `opencart add new page and add all products to it`

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Ossama, that is very smart answer. you really think i came to stackoverflow first? or i googled the problem first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this module which is free to use.
https://webocreation.com/blog/show-all-products-opencart-module

Installation:

Unzip “Show+All+Products+Module.zip” in folder of your choice.
Upload all the files to the root folder to your server, no files are overwritten.
Be sure you have VqMod installed.